# RegEx replace with caret

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does

```
var a = "1ab";
a = a.replace(/[^\d][a-z]/g, "");
```

remove "a" and "b"? I thought that it should remove only "b" because "a" is preceeded by a number which I excluded by [^\d].

Who can help me?

Comment: `a = a.match(/[^\d][a-z]/g, "");` try this and you'll see what your code matches

Comment: As you can see from the answers there are plenty of people that can help you with this, but you may want to be a little bit more accurate about what exactly you want. There are many ways of removing the b, it would be good if you specified what your rule is for which things to keep and which to discard.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I see your point! In this special case I actually did not understand why RegExp behaved in this manner. Of course there is a programming task behind all this, but it had nothing to do with this special problem. I am new to RegExp and I did not know that capture groups even exist. Now I do :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It removes them because your character class `[^\d]` means "anything that is not a digit." The `^` means "not" and `\d` means "digit". So your expression means "match anything that is not a digit followed by any lowercase letter", which matches `"ab"`.

To remove only lowercase letters that don't have a digit in front of them, it's probably easiest to do it with a capture group:

```
a = a.replace(/([\d][a-z])[a-z]/g, "$1");
```

That says: Match a digit followed by a lowercase letter (as a group) followed by a lowercase letter (outside the group), and replace it with just the group's contents. If you want to remove `"c"` from `"1abc"`, add a `+` after the last `[a-z]`, e.g.: `/([\d][a-z])[a-z]+/g`.

Comment: Ahhh. Got it! So what would be the expression for: all characters not preceeded by a digit?

Comment: @heinob: I added an expression to help with `1ab`, but it's not as general as "all characers not preceded by a digit."

Answer (score 2):

Your regex says to replace a character that is NOT a digit followed by a character that is a-z with nothing and replace all matches it finds.

In your string 1ab, it will first match the `a` as NOT a digit and then the `b` as a-z so you will be left with "1" in your string.

If you want to find a number follow by a single letter and extract just that, I'd suggest this:

```
var match = a.match(/\d[a-z]/);
if (match) {
    var result = match[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is doing exactly what it says:

```
var a = "1ab";
a = a.replace(/[^\d][a-z]/g, "");
...............a....b
```

It's replacing ab with ""

If you want to replace only letters not preceeded by a digit you can do:

```
a.replace(/([^\d])[a-z]/g, "$1");
............a.....b   ......a
```

It's replacing ab with the first match "a"

Answer (score 0):

What you want is likely a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), in other words the regex should be `/(?!<\d)[a-z]/g`. This finding any (lower-case) character not preceded by a digit (which I'm guessing is what you want since you only expected b to be removed).

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have them. (Not my dv, btw.)

Comment: True, I didn't spot it being JS. The obvious solution then is using a capture group, which people have already covered.